# How can I make my uitextfield look like it is caving in?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

How can I make my uitextfield to how it is kind of caving in in the picture? I believe that is called an inset? How can I accomplish this?

[image]

Comment: Do you want space on left or right side? or do you want your textfield look like this?

Comment: This looks like a custom UITextField background image. Possibly made by combining a UIView with a UIImageView (for the background and the icon) and a UITextField for the text with no border. This is not a standard UITextField.

Comment: @Lion I would like it to look like the one in the image :S

Comment: It is image man. You can make image looks like this and set as background image to textfield having no border!

Comment: Alright thank you.

Comment: This doesn't look like an image since it fits so perfectly in the background. It's simply a `UITextField` with semi-transparent black background and an inwards shadow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, you can set the `BorderStyle` property to `Bezel` as

```
myTextField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.Bezel
myTextField.layer.cornerRadius = 5
myTextField.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor() //Any Color you want
```

But if you want to give the effect as display in the image, you need to customise the `UITextField`